# how to find a letter in a string and how to return two strings in alphabetical order? java

Tags: java, string, substring, alphabetical

How can I print which word comes first (alphabetically) when I prompts the user to write two words? and how to check if a certain character exist in that scanned words?

For ex: if the user wrote "Word" and "Apple" how can I print these two words in alphabetical order. Also, I wrote a program to check if char 'z' appears on either words or not, but I don't know what's wrong about it? Here is my program:

```
import java.util.*;
public class Pr7{
  public static void main(String[] args){

    //print two words and read them..

    Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);    
    String Word1;
    String Word2;

    System.out.println();

    System.out.print("* Please write one word: ");
       Word1 = scan.nextLine();
    System.out.print("* Please write one word: ");
       Word2 = scan.nextLine();

    //Prints which word has more characters in it..

    if (Word1.length() > Word2.length())
       System.out.println("- " + "(" + Word1 + ")" + " has more characters.");

    else if (Word2.length() > Word1.length())
       System.out.println("- " + "(" + Word2 + ")" + " has more characters.");
    else
       System.out.println("- " + "(" + Word1 + ")" + " has equal characters with " + "(" + Word2 + ")");

    //Prints which word comes first (alphabetically)..
/*    
    char ch;
    int compare = Word1.compareTO(Word2);  
*/

   //Prints whether the letter 'z' appears in either word..

   if (Word1.indexOf('z') == true)
     System.out.print("- Letter 'z' appears in the first word.");
   else if (Word2.indexOf('z') == )
     System.out.print("- Letter 'z' appears in the second word.");
   else 
     System.out.print("- Letter 'z' doesn't appears in either word.");

    System.out.println();

   //Prompts the user for a sentence and reads it.. 

   String Str1;
   String Str2;

    System.out.println();

    System.out.print("* Please write a string: ");
       Str1 = scan.nextLine();
    System.out.print("* Please write a string: ");
       Str2 = scan.nextLine();

   //Prints how many characters are in the first sentence and the second sentence..

    if (Str1.length() > Str2.length()){
       System.out.println("- " + "(" + Str1 + ")" + " has more characters.");
       System.out.print("- " + "(" + Str1 + ")" + " = " + Str2.length() + " Character(s)" +  " && " + "(" + Word2 + ")" + " = " + Word2.length() + " Character(s)");
    }
    else if (Str2.length() > Str1.length()){
       System.out.println("- " + "(" + Str2 + ")" + " has more characters.");
       System.out.print("- " + "(" + Str2 + ")" + " = " + Str2.length() + " Character(s)" + " && " + "(" + Word1 + ")" + " = " + Word1.length() + " Character(s)");
    }
    else{
       System.out.println("- " + "(" + Str1 + ")" + " has equal characters with " + "(" + Str2 + ")");
       System.out.print("- " + "(" + Str1 + ")" + " = " + Str1.length() + " Character(s)" + " && " + "(" + Word2 + ")" + " = " + Word2.length() + " Character(s)");  
    }     


    System.out.println();

  }//main
}//Pr7
```

I know the methods I need to call, but I don't know how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

To sort a list of strings in alphabetical order, you can do the following:

```
List<String> lst = new ArrayList<>();
lst.add("asd");
lst.add("ffsd");

Collections.sort(lst, new Comparator<String>() {
  @Override
  public int compare(String foo, String bar) {
    return String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER.compare(foo, bar);
  }
});

// will print the first of the sorted strings
System.out.println(lst.get(0));
```